# What is the difference between WebSocket `closing` vs `closed` readyState?

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, web-standards

[`WebSocket.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState) can be `CONNECTING`, `OPEN`, `CLOSING` or `CLOSED`. What is the difference between `CLOSING` and `CLOSED` states? Why is it useful to distinguish between these two states? Can I treat a `CLOSING` websocket the same as a `CLOSED` websocket?

Answer (score 1):

In the `CLOSING` state, the WebSocket has sent a Close packet to the peer indicating that the connection is being intentionally ended and why, and is awaiting a reply from the peer. The TCP connection is still open at this stage.

In the `CLOSED` state, the TCP connection has been closed, or was not successfully opened to begin with.